# How to set BottonNavigationBar backgroundColor depending on each scaffold backgroundColor?

Tags: flutter, dart

how Can I change my navBar backgroundColor dynamically depending on every Scaffold? All pages are in separate file of course :D

I mean, here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
  body: pages[currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```

Also, I've created a List of pages:

```
List pages = const [
MyHomePage(),
BarItem(),
SearchPage(),
MyPage(),
```

Every page has different Scaffold backgroundColor.

Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Colors list same as Pages.

```
List bgColors = [
Colors.blue,
Colors.red,
Colors.yellow,
Colors.black,
```

And add the list values as background color.

```
Scaffold(
  body: pages[currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: bgColors[currentIndex],
```